# Odoo 9 : How to show form view of an object from js using (action_manager)?

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-9

I am trying to show form view of a specific object through js code using `self.action_manager.do_action`.

**Code to show Tree View of a specific record**

```
self.action_manager.do_action({
                type: 'ir.actions.act_window',
                view_type: 'list',
                view_mode: 'list,form',
                res_model: res_model,
                domain: [['id', '=', res_id]],
                views: [[false, 'list'], [false, 'form']],
                target: 'new'
            });
```

This code works and helps me open up a **Tree View** of the given res_model with res_id. But I would like to know how to call and show **Form View** of the same record. I have tried using the 'form' instead of 'list' in above code as follows,

**Code tried to show Form View of a specific record**

```
            view_type: 'form',
            view_mode: 'form',
            res_model: res_model,
            domain: [['id', '=', res_id]],
            views: [[false, 'form']],
            target: 'current'
```

**And this doesn't help.**.

Can anyone help me on this. Basically i have the record details in js and want to display the record in its own form view. Thanks a lot for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use form view id to specify which form to show and you will need to specify the `view_mode`.
To view a specific record you have to pass the record id as `res_id`, see below:

```
var model_obj = new instance.web.Model('ir.model.data');
view_id = model_obj.call('get_object_reference',
                          ["your_module_name_here", 
                           "your_form_xml_id_here"
                          ]
                        );

var view_manager = self.view.getParent(),
action_manager = view_manager.getParent();
self.view.destroy();
action_manager.do_action({
            type: 'ir.actions.act_window',
            res_model: res_model,
            res_id: res_id,
            view_mode: 'form',
            views: [[view_id, 'form']],
            target: 'current'
          });
```

Comment: Hi, WalR, currently I use self.action_manager = new ActionManager(self); self.action_manager.do_action({}) method to call the form view here.I have tried your logic and it does not supporting me.I think the 'action_manager' support only the target:'new' and view_mode: 'list'. If we use view_mode as form view the self.action_manager.do_action({}) function is not working. It shows the error as "TypeError: this.main_control_panel is undefined".Could you help me how to use your logic with self.action_manager = new ActionManager(self); self.action_manager.do_action method?

Comment: Hi WalR, I am using this logic in wizard popup window.I have tried self.do_action too but it shows error as "TypeError: self.do_action is not a function"